# JSON PHP parse error

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, wampserver

I'm getting this error:

> Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\wamp\www\test.php
>   in line 2

while trying to print the keys from [Reddit's front page](http://www.reddit.com/.json)

How do I fix *$json_string* parse error and display the keys from [Reddit's front page](http://www.reddit.com/.json)? Thanks in advance.

**test.php**

```
   <?php
        $json_string = "{"kind": "Listing", "data": {"modhash": "", "children": [{"kind": "t3", "data": {"domain": "i.imgur.com", "banned_by": null, "media_embed": {}, "subreddit": "pics", "selftext_html": null, "selftext": "", "likes": null, "link_flair_text": null, "id": "1d7lch", "clicked": false, "title": "Graves of a Catholic woman and her Protestant husband, who were not allowed to be buried together.", ... ";

        $a = json_decode($json_string);
        echo $a.keys();
    ?>
```

Comment: http://es1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Perhaps you should learn about basic PHP syntax, particularly in relation to strings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put it into a string yourself, just use this.

```
    $a = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.reddit.com/.json'));
```

That will take care of the escaping for you.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it inside single quotes or escape the double quotes?

Comment: +1 Thanks for your reply. I tried that but I got the same exact error. What I'm I doing wrong? $json_string = '{"kind": "Listing", "data": {"modhash": "", "children": [ ... ';

Comment: Check user203968s response.

Comment: +1 Thank you dansaania. Your recommendation for using addslashes was helpful

Answer (score 2):

Use ' for opening and closing the tags for $json_string like so:

```
$json_string='{"king": "Listing", ...}';
```

OR escape the characters " inside the string:

```
$json_string="{\"king\": \"Listing\", ...}";
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for your response. I'm not sure why my single quotes are giving me the same error. Escaping every "" will be too much.

Comment: `$json_string = addslashes("{"king": "Listing", ...}");`

Comment: addslashes will escape both `'` and `"` however.

Comment: +1 Thank you user2036968 for explaning how to use the single and double quotes in this case. Very helpful